# How do I add custom import paths for my JavaScript Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import, configuration

I've had a look around google and could not find anything on it. I was wondering if it is possible to change the import path within my React project from this:

```js
import {XComponent} from '../../../../components/XComponent';
```

To This:

```js
import {XComponent} from '@components/XComponent';
```

So adding something in the project configuration to link a specific folder to a custom path in this case `@components`, which would really help clean up the imports.

Thanks

Comment: Depends what bundling tool you are using or IDE. For instance, for webpack there is an option https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias

Comment: Hi @IgorBukin, thanks for the fast response. In my case I am using babel as the bundler as well as VS Code as the IDE. Any ideas if it is possible with this setup?

Comment: I use jsconfig.json file in the root of the project folder for that. There is an option to specify the aliases as well https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've managed to get it to work within the project. I had to modify the babel configuration as well as the tsconfig and its all good.